# Installing sleuthkit on macOS sierra newest version fails

Tags: git, make

So I have a completely fresh install of macOS sierra updated to the newest version.

When I run `./configure` everything checks out and when I run `make` it returns this:

```
Making all in tsk
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in base
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT md5c.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/md5c.Tpo -c -o md5c.lo md5c.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT md5c.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/md5c.Tpo -c md5c.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/md5c.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT md5c.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/md5c.Tpo -c md5c.c -o md5c.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/md5c.Tpo .deps/md5c.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT mymalloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/mymalloc.Tpo -c -o mymalloc.lo mymalloc.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT mymalloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/mymalloc.Tpo -c mymalloc.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/mymalloc.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT mymalloc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/mymalloc.Tpo -c mymalloc.c -o mymalloc.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/mymalloc.Tpo .deps/mymalloc.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT sha1c.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sha1c.Tpo -c -o sha1c.lo sha1c.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT sha1c.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sha1c.Tpo -c sha1c.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/sha1c.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT sha1c.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sha1c.Tpo -c sha1c.c -o sha1c.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/sha1c.Tpo .deps/sha1c.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT crc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/crc.Tpo -c -o crc.lo crc.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT crc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/crc.Tpo -c crc.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/crc.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT crc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/crc.Tpo -c crc.c -o crc.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/crc.Tpo .deps/crc.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_endian.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_endian.Tpo -c -o tsk_endian.lo tsk_endian.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_endian.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_endian.Tpo -c tsk_endian.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_endian.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_endian.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_endian.Tpo -c tsk_endian.c -o tsk_endian.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_endian.Tpo .deps/tsk_endian.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_error.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_error.Tpo -c -o tsk_error.lo tsk_error.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_error.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_error.Tpo -c tsk_error.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_error.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_error.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_error.Tpo -c tsk_error.c -o tsk_error.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_error.Tpo .deps/tsk_error.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_list.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_list.Tpo -c -o tsk_list.lo tsk_list.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_list.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_list.Tpo -c tsk_list.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_list.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_list.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_list.Tpo -c tsk_list.c -o tsk_list.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_list.Tpo .deps/tsk_list.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_parse.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_parse.Tpo -c -o tsk_parse.lo tsk_parse.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_parse.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_parse.Tpo -c tsk_parse.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_parse.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_parse.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_parse.Tpo -c tsk_parse.c -o tsk_parse.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_parse.Tpo .deps/tsk_parse.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_printf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_printf.Tpo -c -o tsk_printf.lo tsk_printf.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_printf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_printf.Tpo -c tsk_printf.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_printf.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_printf.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_printf.Tpo -c tsk_printf.c -o tsk_printf.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_printf.Tpo .deps/tsk_printf.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_unicode.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_unicode.Tpo -c -o tsk_unicode.lo tsk_unicode.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_unicode.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_unicode.Tpo -c tsk_unicode.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_unicode.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_unicode.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_unicode.Tpo -c tsk_unicode.c -o tsk_unicode.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_unicode.Tpo .deps/tsk_unicode.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_version.Tpo -c -o tsk_version.lo tsk_version.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_version.Tpo -c tsk_version.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_version.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_version.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_version.Tpo -c tsk_version.c -o tsk_version.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_version.Tpo .deps/tsk_version.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_stack.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_stack.Tpo -c -o tsk_stack.lo tsk_stack.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_stack.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_stack.Tpo -c tsk_stack.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_stack.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_stack.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_stack.Tpo -c tsk_stack.c -o tsk_stack.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_stack.Tpo .deps/tsk_stack.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT XGetopt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/XGetopt.Tpo -c -o XGetopt.lo XGetopt.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT XGetopt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/XGetopt.Tpo -c XGetopt.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/XGetopt.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT XGetopt.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/XGetopt.Tpo -c XGetopt.c -o XGetopt.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/XGetopt.Tpo .deps/XGetopt.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_lock.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_lock.Tpo -c -o tsk_lock.lo tsk_lock.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_lock.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_lock.Tpo -c tsk_lock.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_lock.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_lock.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_lock.Tpo -c tsk_lock.c -o tsk_lock.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_lock.Tpo .deps/tsk_lock.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -Wall  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT tsk_error_win32.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_error_win32.Tpo -c -o tsk_error_win32.lo tsk_error_win32.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_error_win32.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_error_win32.Tpo -c tsk_error_win32.cpp  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/tsk_error_win32.o
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT tsk_error_win32.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tsk_error_win32.Tpo -c tsk_error_win32.cpp -o tsk_error_win32.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/tsk_error_win32.Tpo .deps/tsk_error_win32.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2  -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -L/usr/local/lib -o libtskbase.la  md5c.lo mymalloc.lo sha1c.lo crc.lo tsk_endian.lo tsk_error.lo tsk_list.lo tsk_parse.lo tsk_printf.lo tsk_unicode.lo tsk_version.lo tsk_stack.lo XGetopt.lo tsk_lock.lo tsk_error_win32.lo  -lewf -ldl -lz -lafflib -ldl -lstdc++ 
libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libtskbase.a .libs/md5c.o .libs/mymalloc.o .libs/sha1c.o .libs/crc.o .libs/tsk_endian.o .libs/tsk_error.o .libs/tsk_list.o .libs/tsk_parse.o .libs/tsk_printf.o .libs/tsk_unicode.o .libs/tsk_version.o .libs/tsk_stack.o .libs/XGetopt.o .libs/tsk_lock.o .libs/tsk_error_win32.o 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libtskbase.a(XGetopt.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libtskbase.a(tsk_error_win32.o) has no symbols
libtool: link: ranlib .libs/libtskbase.a
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libtskbase.a(XGetopt.o) has no symbols
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: .libs/libtskbase.a(tsk_error_win32.o) has no symbols
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libtskbase.la" && ln -s "../libtskbase.la" "libtskbase.la" )
Making all in img
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -I./../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT img_open.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/img_open.Tpo -c -o img_open.lo img_open.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -I./../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT img_open.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/img_open.Tpo -c img_open.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/img_open.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -I./../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT img_open.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/img_open.Tpo -c img_open.c -o img_open.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/img_open.Tpo .deps/img_open.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -I./../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT img_types.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/img_types.Tpo -c -o img_types.lo img_types.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -I./../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT img_types.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/img_types.Tpo -c img_types.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/img_types.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -I./../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT img_types.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/img_types.Tpo -c img_types.c -o img_types.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/img_types.Tpo .deps/img_types.Plo
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk  -I../.. -I./../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -MT raw.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/raw.Tpo -c -o raw.lo raw.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../tsk -I../.. -I./../.. -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT raw.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/raw.Tpo -c raw.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/raw.o

raw.c:91:32: error: no member named 'images' in 'IMG_RAW_INFO'
                open(raw_info->images[idx], O_RDONLY | O_BINARY)) < 0) {
                     ~~~~~~~~  ^

raw.c:96:38: error: no member named 'images' in 'IMG_RAW_INFO'
                "\" - %s", raw_info->images[idx], strerror(errno));
                           ~~~~~~~~  ^

raw.c:160:63: error: no member named 'images' in 'IMG_RAW_INFO'
                "\" offset %" PRIuOFF " seek - %s", raw_info->images[idx],
                                                    ~~~~~~~~  ^

raw.c:172:64: error: no member named 'images' in 'IMG_RAW_INFO'
            PRIuOFF " read len: %" PRIuSIZE " - %s", raw_info->images[idx],

                                                     ~~~~~~~~  ^

4 errors generated.

make[3]: *** [raw.lo] Error 1

make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I haven't been able to find my issue happening for someone else so I hope someone can help me here?

```
java - newest version (installed today)
java sdk - newest version (installed today)
autoconf  2.69
automake 1.15
libtool -V returns `Apple Inc. version cctools-895`  asking brew im told 2.4.6_1
afflib 3.7.15
libewf 20140608_1
```

Now I know I can just run `brew install sleuthkit` but I'm not satisfied with that as it doesn't install for ewf format and I'm following tutorials for that exact format.

In advance, many thanks to everyone using their time on this!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that build has some version mixup? The `images` member was removed from `IMG_RAW_INFO` in `raw.h` in the latest version.

Look at this diff:

https://github.com/sleuthkit/sleuthkit/commit/20a63c73a646582cdf28b68984ae6551c4cc6ee6#diff-a911f4b3448816add1cf4ede8d8a168a

```
  typedef struct {
      TSK_IMG_INFO img_info;
-        int num_img;
         uint8_t is_winobj;

         // the following are protected by cache_lock in IMG_INFO
-        TSK_TCHAR **images;
         TSK_OFF_T *max_off;
         int *cptr;              /* exists for each image - points to entry in cache */
         IMG_SPLIT_CACHE cache[SPLIT_CACHE];     /* small number of fds for open images */
```

No idea if that helps, but maybe clean everything up and download and unpack the latest version once more.